# Securely transfer Username and Password in login.jsp without https

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts

I have an struts application where I need to transfer username and password over http.
but that username and password are transferred in plaintext can be viewd by pressing Control+Shift+J.

Any suggestion how to secure login data ?
i.e it shouldn't be visible in plaint text format

Note--That login credentials are verified using database and LDAP

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can hash password and then send the Username + password hash to server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a form submission in login.jsp to submit username and password.

Use HTTP POST instead of GET:

In your login.jsp, use http method as POST

```
<form action="welcome.jsp" method="post">
```

Both GET and POST method is used to transfer data from client to server in HTTP protocol but Main difference between POST and GET method is that GET carries request parameter appended in URL string(as plaintext and can be viewed from browser) while POST carries request parameter in message body which makes it more secure way of transferring data from client to server in http protocol.

More to read about Post: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

EDIT:

Encrypt data in browser (Javascript way):

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="md5.js" language="javascript" >
  console.log("md5.js script loaded");
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function doLogin()
{
  document.formname.hash.value=MD5(document.formname.password.value);
  document.formname.password.value = "";
  document.formname.submit();
}

</script>
```

For form submit button,

```
<input onClick="doLogin(); return true;" type="submit" value="Login">
```

Comment: That does essentially nothing "secure" at all. It keeps it out of the URL, and that's it.

Comment: Yes I am already using post and I can see username and password in body

Comment: @MebinJoe OP *specifically* asked how to *secure* the data. Sending as a POST request isn't "secure" at all, as I said.

Comment: @Dave Newton Okay. I have updated the answer with hashing plain text from front-end using JS

Comment: I also tried with HTTPS but the password is still visible in the form body in the developer console

Comment: @MebinJoe I am  trying to encrypt the password using RSA public key in client side than decrypt it in the server side using RSA private key

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL(Https) in order to securely post your data. Though the form data is visible to a user on his/her browser under the Dev Tools, no one else can intercept the posted data when the connection is secure.

- Even if you encrypt post data before POST, the data can still been seen in the console as the HTML/Form data is visible.